Animated movie (possibly stop-motion animation) where a side character gets super strength from sucking in his long hair
This cartoon movie (possibly stop-motion) was some sort of a journey. The main character was, I think, a little boy.
Along his journey he gained several companions with special abilities that proved useful at one point or another. The character I remember best is an old man with very, very long hair, who at one point "sucked in" his hair until it looked like he had a military flattop cut (kind of like Guile from Streetfighter); his body became like a body builder and he gained super strength, which he used to pull something (maybe the ground...I'm not sure).
I likely watched it between 1993 and 1998.

Hmmm... I say I believe it was movie length, but I honestly don't know for sure.

I have been racking my brain to remember more details: the animation style was similar to James and the Giant Peach.

In the scene where the old, long-haired man used his power, they were needing to get to the next place quickly. Instead of running to get there, he picked up the ground and pulled it to them.

More on the animation style: I remember them talking with the top of their heads moving instead of their bottom jaws.

The top of their heads were not connected, so the movement was not so much like a puppet (not hinged), but more strait up and down like a lid to a pot.
